# How to use char data type with if in C?

Tags: c, string, char

The code is,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    int a, b, s;
    char ch;
LOOP:
    printf("enter digits \t");
    scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
    s = a + b;
    printf("\n answer is %d", s);

    printf("\n add another no.? (yes/no) : \t");
    scanf("%c", &ch);
    if (ch == "yes")
        goto LOOP;
    if (ch == "no")
        printf("\n Okay bye !!! ");
    exit(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone tell why this ain't working? When it asks:

```
Add another no.?
```

I cant type anything, I type but nothing gets print.

Thx in advanced.

Comment: You should learn to use a for and while loop instead of "goto LOOP".

Comment: You can't compare c strings with ==, use strcmp(s1, s2).

Comment: I know goto is not good.

Comment: ... And sort out the indentation. BTW - Cannot compare a string with a character. Does this even compile?

Comment: `ch == "yes"` is incorrect, `ch` is `char` while `"yes"` is `char *`. You want `ch == '1'`.

Comment: @EdHeal Yes it compiles

Comment: "yes" is not a char, but array of 4 chars. so convert your `c` into array, scanf `%s` into it, and strcmp(c,"yes");. something like that

Comment: @user3551432 - Put on the warnings.

Comment: Try `if (ch == '1') ... // yes` and `if (ch == '0') ... // no`.

Comment: you should notice the warnings. A program compiles without error doesn't mean that it runs fine without error

Comment: Why do you include `string.h` then do nothing with it? Why do you ask "add another no.? **1** for yes / **0** for no" then comparing the result with *yes* and *no*. You scan only 1 character so if you enter more characters, nothing will be displayed, that's why you didn't see it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First if you want to store "yes" you will need a char array, not a single char.

Then you can not compare char arrays with string literals like this: `ch == "yes"`, you have to use "string compare", `strcmp` or `strncmp`.

Answer (score 0):

"yes" is a char*(or pointer to char), which can't be compared using ==. In this case you need to use the library function strncmp() which compares two strings. Also a char is a data type which typically holds one byte of information in which case a single char cannot contain the 3 character string "yes". In your use of scanf to populate &ch, ch will end up only containing the first char of the input due to char's size.

Answer (score 0):

Your code says to input 1 for yes and 0 for no, whereas you are checking for ch=="yes" and ch =="no".

You can initialize an integer, say, `int choice;` and then:

```
printf("\n add another no.? 1 for yes / 0 for no : \t");
    scanf("%i", &choice);
    if (choice == 1)
        goto LOOP;
    if (choice == 0){
        printf("\n Okay bye !!! ");
    exit(0);
    }
```

NOTE that the exit(0) should be inside the if() statement, i.e. between {curly brackets}. When we don't use {curly brackets} with if() statement, only the first piece of code after the if(), that is `printf();` in this case, is taken with the if().

Secondly, if you want to use yes and no instead of 1 and 0, then in that case you cant compare a string with == operator. To compare two string you use strcmp function, which returns 0 if the strings are same and some positive or negative value if not same. (that's why we have to use ! operator with strcmp, so that in case strings are same, and the strcmp return 0, !0 becomes 1 which means true and if statement is executed.)

We initialize ch, a string as `char ch[5];` and then:

```
printf("\n add another no.? yes for yes / no for no : \t");
    scanf("%s", ch);
    if (!strcmp(ch,"yes"))
        goto LOOP;
    if (!strcmp(ch,"no")){
        printf("\n Okay bye !!! ");
    exit(0);
    }
```